# Android Firestore "whereEqualTo" and "whereArrayContains" alongwith orderBy clause not working

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from Firestore using multiple where clause and `orderBy` clause but I am not getting expected result .

```java
firebaseChatReference.whereEqualTo("companyGuid", customerGuid)
    .whereArrayContains("threadJoinedUserList", mUserId)
    .orderBy("lastMessageServerTime", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
```

In my above query I can't see the effect of orderBy clause .

Comment: What is your issue? Did the query failed or you didn't get expected result? If its the failed query execution, please kindly include your error stack trace. For unexpected result, please go through your data-set using various debug tools. You can also confirm manually if your data-set is manageable.

Comment: @Pusparaj read the last line of the question